# chars().count() time complexity

Tags: rust

I know `str.len()`'s time complexity is *O*(1). What about `chars`? Is the time complexity of `str.chars().count()` *O*(*n*) or *O*(1)?

Also, are there any sites about Rust time complexity like the one for [Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

###### Exhibit A

`str.chars()` returns a [`Chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html) iterator. Take a look at the documentation. There's something *missing*.

You'll notice that `Chars` does not implement the [`ExactSizeIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html) trait. I'd expect it to implement that trait if getting the count were *O*(1).

###### Exhibit B

Scroll down to its implementation of [`Iterator::count`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html#method.count) and we see:

> Consumes the iterator, counting the number of iterations and returning it.

Counting the number of iterations? That's not promising.

###### Exhibit C

Let's look at the [source code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/str/iter.rs.html#47-51), the ultimate source of truth. What do we find?

```
fn count(self) -> usize {
    // length in `char` is equal to the number of non-continuation bytes
    self.iter.filter(|&&byte| !utf8_is_cont_byte(byte)).count()
}
```

Iterate? Filter? Count? The final nail in the coffin.

###### Conclusion

Ladies and gentlemen, it's *O*(*n*). I rest my case!

Comment: And the reason for that is usage of utf8 encoding. This is its downside. Sadly even this method doesn't really give you the length of the string in meaningful human characters, but unicode codepoints. Counting grapheme clusters is a bit different matter... If asker only used ascii, they could just get byte count as the string length with `O(1)` time though. [demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a025d23508e235579d106b86272c4d7c). This does not answer original question so its a comment.